# Views relationship question

Tags: views

I have an Article node type where Expert node's can be referenced via autocompletion (as in: X Expert was consulted for this article)

I created a views for internal use, listing all the experts with exposed filters, easing up the journalist workflow to find suitable experts to contact for certain situations.

I'd like to list under each expert the Article nodes that they were referenced in, but as to how, I'm baffled, I attempted to create a relation with:

```
Content: Expert (field_expert_nid) - reverse
Relate each Content referencing the node through Expert.
```

But that's about how far I've gotten, any help or suggestions how to tackle this greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar situation and resorted to using [viewfield](http://drupal.org/project//viewfield). Works like a charm. Recommended.

Comment: Doesn't that module just enable a Field in content type to be rendered as a view?

Unless this field can be used in view, to show a subview hmm.

Comment: Tested & works.

Comment: As per your question, you probably mean a similarly named module called Views Field View.

Comment: Nope. Adding this Viewfield into a Content Type also enables any View displaying the content show that Viewfield - so basicly you have views rows that have views in them. :)